# Mapping foreign keys of subclasses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have following abstract class:

```
public abstract class ClauseComponent
    {
        public int ClauseComponentId { get; set; }
        public abstract string[] Determinate(ClimateChart chart);
        public abstract List<ClauseComponent> GiveCorrectPath(ClimateChart chart);

        public abstract String GetHtmlCode(Boolean isYes);
        public virtual void Add(Boolean soort, ClauseComponent component)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }

        public ClauseComponent()
        {

        }
    }
```

The Clause class inherits from the abstract class:

```
public class Clause : ClauseComponent
    {

        public virtual ClauseComponent YesClause { get; set; }
        public virtual ClauseComponent NoClause { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; private set; }

        public virtual Parameter Par1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Parameter Par2 { get; set; }
        public int Waarde { get; set; }
        public String Operator { get; set; }

        public Clause()
        {
        }

        public Clause(String name, Parameter par1, String op, int waarde)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Par1 = par1;
            this.Operator = op;
            this.Waarde = waarde;
        }

        public Clause(String name, Parameter par1, Parameter par2)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Par1 = par1;
            this.Par2 = par2;
        }
}
```

This is the mapper of the abstract class (I dont have a mapper for the subclass):

```
public ClauseComponentsMapper()
        {
            ToTable("ClauseComponents");

            // Primary key
            HasKey(c => c.ClauseComponentId);

            // Properties
            Property(c => c.ClauseComponentId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        }
```

I have this in my DB:

[image: Database values]

Now I want to give a proper name to the mapping, how can I accomplish this?
I have never done the mapping on abstract classes and subclasses so I'm a little bit in the blue here.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create properties for the mapping columns, and in the mapping class, map the virtual property using the mapping column property.

E.g.

```
public class Clause : ClauseComponent
{
    public int MyCustomPar1Id{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MyCustomPar1Id")]
    public virtual Parameter Par1 { get; set; }       
}
```

Or Fluent Api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Clause >().HasRequired(p => p.Par1 ) // Or Optional
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.MyCustomPar1Id);
```

Comment: Let me know if it works, i haven't tested it, but if memory serves me right, it should work

Comment: Tried it, and didn't work ... where should I place the code of the fluent api? In what mapper? Because I only have a mapper of the abstract class.